# Finding Xpath - for text without HTML tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
    <p class="result-price">
    <span>Price</span>
    $25.00 |
    <span>Member Price</span>
    $25.00
    <span>(0% discount)</span>
    </p>
    <p class="result-rating">
```

From the above HTML tags u can notice that the $25.00 | is just a text and is not associated with any HTML tags, I wrote the following x-path to retrieve it :

`//div[contains(@data-title,'Rafael B.: Arrangement and Composition')]/div[3]/p[1]/text()`[2].

and it did extract the text but in the xpath checker the result is displayed inside a container. 
when I use the same x-path in my script, its not retrieving the text value.

Can somebody please help.Looks like the text is inside a container/ text-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for selenium webdriver to extract something like this directly. Because, **even if it might show as the xpath resulting in an element (when using Firepath)**, but still it will raise an **InvalidSelectorException**. So, I think the only way to get the text, is to get the innerHTML/text of the parent node and then use **"substring()"** or **"split"** to extract the required text.

As per above html snippet, you can use the below **Java Code** to get the output as "$25.00 |":-

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='result-price']")).getText().substring(6, 14); // Output will be $25.00 |

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Glad that it worked it out.. Please consider marking it as an answer and/or upvoting it.. Cheers. :)

Comment: Since i am new user i cannot Upvote it.. but have marked it as answer.. Thanks Again..

Comment: Okay.. No problem.. :)

Comment: This is not at all a good solution because it hardcodes the substring values.

Comment: @mugen:  I get why you have pointed out that. But, since the text is not associated with any HTML tags, there is no simple way. If you have anything to extract it finely, I would be grateful too.. Thanks 

Answer (score 12):

Here a way to retrieve price :

```
//span[text()="Price"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

or

```
//p[@class="result-price"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: The above code, when executed for retrieving text results in this exception: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException**.

Answer (score 3):

**Here the easiest way:**

```
//p[contains(.,'$25.00')]
```

**or you can find any text like below**

```
//p[contains(.,'%replaceText%')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !