# Getting a value using xpath in <li>and <span> t

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

Needed to get this value using xpath.
[image]

Have tried two different xpaths but along with this value "Model:" is also coming. The two xpaths I have tried are

```
//*[@id="description"]/ul/li[2] and //*[@id="description"]/ul/li[2]/text()
```

But same results.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172216/finding-xpath-for-text-without-html-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first XPath expression selects the second `li`, which includes the `span` containing the text "Model:".

In your second XPath expression you select the text node which is a direct child of the second `li`. That looks correct to me:

```
//*[@id="description"]/ul/li[2]/text()
```

I suspect that this is an issue with Selenium rather than with your XPath itself. Selenium may be selecting the `li` element anyway, rather than the text node. If that's true, you might have more luck with this:

```
substring-after(//*[@id="description"]/ul/li[2], 'Model:')
```